# Exporting Mongo database fields in txt

Tags: python, mongodb

I would like to export my `Mongo` database in text format. I use the `Ubuntu terminal` to generate the command which, in general, works very well. the command goes like this:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db twitter-tweets-database --collection
realtargettweetstable --csv --out /home/sulkhan/Desktop/oilprice.txt --
fields text,timestamp_ms
```

I get an error however, when I use this command:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db twitter-tweets-database --collection
realtargettweetstable --csv --out /home/sulkhan/Desktop/oilprice.txt
--fields text,timestamp_ms,crude oil_sentiment
```

The error says:

> ERROR: too many positional options

My only guess is that the error is caused by the header: `crude oil_sentiment`. This header (field) differs from other fields only by the space between the crude AND oil.

**How can I export this header without an error?**

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `crude oil_sentiment` to `crude\ oil_sentiment`

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db twitter-tweets-database --collection
realtargettweetstable --csv --out /home/sulkhan/Desktop/oilprice.txt
--fields text,timestamp_ms,crude\ oil_sentiment
```